# Importing an exported function with name in Typescript

Tags: typescript, module

I know that for classes in an export, you can singularly grab classes like so:

```
import {classA, classB} from "largeExport";
```

However given an export that contains a function, where it would be used as such:

```
var sum = require("myAdder")(1, 2)
```

How do you import it with it's own name?

I know you can import the whole thing and use the function like this:

```
import * as adder from "myAdder";
var sum = adder(1, 2);
```

however the export that I'm working with is actually quite big, and importing the whole thing is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

its not about "classes" but the way it's been exported

if it was exported as

```
export const x = "x";
export class X {};
```

then

```
import {x, X} from "./x";
```

or

```
import * as xxx from "./x"
import x = xxx.x;
import X = xxx.X;
```

if

```
const x = "x";
export default x;
export class X {};
```

then

```
import x from "./x"
```

or

```
import x, {X} from "./x"
```

and you will be importing the whole file anyway

if you are concerned about import sizes you might want to split you module into many, more modular files.